# window decoration glitch with nvidia driver 495 and 510

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, 21.10

With Ubuntu 21.10, with nvidia driver package 495 and 510 I have the graphics glitch after each login. The icons in the top bad of the window seem distorted by their upscaled "shadows"

This can be removed by restarting the gnome-shell (alt+f2 and then "r" command).
Under 470 no such error exist,

I would like to ask for suggestions. What exactly is responsible for drawing the  "minimize" "full screen" "close window" buttons. I would like to pursue the issue, but given no error messages that seem in any way related, I am stuck.

[image]